# k8s: expose directly udp port (no http) using traefik

Tags: kubernetes, graylog2, traefik-ingress

I've just deployed graylog on my kubernetes cluster.

I need to be able to expose udp port as ingress rule, under graylog.localhost/gelf. Currently, my services are:

```
$ kubectl get service -o wide -l app.kubernetes.io/name=graylog
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE   SELECTOR
graylog-1583177737-master   ClusterIP   10.43.131.54    <none>        9000/TCP    20m   app.kubernetes.io/instance=graylog-1583177737,app.kubernetes.io/name=graylog,graylog-role=master
graylog-1583177737-web      ClusterIP   10.43.141.128   <none>        9000/TCP    20m   app.kubernetes.io/instance=graylog-1583177737,app.kubernetes.io/name=graylog
graylog-1583177737-udp      ClusterIP   10.43.188.69    <none>        12201/UDP   20m   app.kubernetes.io/instance=graylog-1583177737,app.kubernetes.io/name=graylog
```

My service `graylog-1583177737-udp` is as below:

```
$ kubectl describe service graylog-1583177737-udp
Name:              graylog-1583177737-udp
Namespace:         graylog
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/component=UDP
                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=graylog-1583177737
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=graylog
                   app.kubernetes.io/version=3.1
                   helm.sh/chart=graylog-1.5.2
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/instance=graylog-1583177737,app.kubernetes.io/name=graylog
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.43.188.69
Port:              gelf  12201/UDP
TargetPort:        12201/UDP
Endpoints:         10.42.0.48:12201,10.42.1.47:12201
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

My ingress controller is traefik.

Comment: Have you checked official documentation of [Traefik.io: Entrypoint UDP](https://docs.traefik.io/master/routing/entrypoints/)

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I am wrong but it will be possible with new version of traefik `2.2`.

The `UDP` support as described on Github traefik's project page: [Github.com: traefik project site](https://github.com/containous/traefik/projects/3?card_filter_query=udp) will be available in the version `2.2` which is now a release candidate.

On the time of writing this, the current newest downloadable version of traefik from docker image repository is version `2.1.6`.

Please have a look at:

- [Github.com: Traefik UDP support issue](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/5048#)
- [Traefik.io: Entrypoints with UDP support on version 2.2](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.2/routing/entrypoints/)
- [Traefik.io: Services on version 2.2](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.2/routing/services/)
- [Traefik.io: Entrypoints on version 2.1 (latest)](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/entrypoints/)

Please let me know if you have any questions on that.